# Which python library for parsing Linux ELF files?

Tags: binary-analysis, linux, idapython, elf, python

I want to be able to parse 32 and 64 bit ELF files - but not create or modify them (e.g. as discussed in [this thread](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1843/what-are-the-available-libraries-to-statically-modify-elf-executables)). The ELF binaries may possibly come from embedded Linux systems, that is, the library should not be irritated by MIPS, ARM and other non-x86 architectures.

What I have considered:

- [pyelftools](https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools) (my currently favored option)
- [pylibelf](https://github.com/crackinglandia/pylibelf)
- [pydevtools](https://code.google.com/p/pydevtools/)
- Also an option: using a C library and ctypes.

Do I have forgotten something?
Which of the above options would you prefer?

For those who had some practical experience with pylibelf or pydeftools: These seem no longer updated (last commit: 2013 and 2012), are they mature enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at radare2. It can parse file formats (see [here](http://radare.today/parsing-a-fileformat-with-radare2/) for an example of parsing the ELF header).

Radare2 supports multiple architectures and is being actively developed. On top of that it has bindings for a lot of languages, including Python of course. Read through the [bindings source code](https://github.com/radare/radare2-bindings) to see it is pretty straightforward to script it.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for your pointer! Radare2 seems to be a powerful framework but may be a bit too heavy for my task. Have you tried one of the mentioned libraries whose main/only objective is to parse ELF files? In case their parsing capabilities are as good the ones of Radare2, I would prefer a more light-weight solution ...

Answer (score 2):

[LIEF](https://lief-project.github.io/) is a good choice for parsing ELF binaries. It's written in C++, but comes with proper [Python bindings](https://pypi.org/project/lief/) and is readily [available via PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/lief/). Besides parsing ELF files it also supports Windows PE and MacOS binaries, reading *and* modifying and writing all of them, that is.

It's available since 2017 and is [actively maintained (example)](https://lief-project.github.io/blog/2022-01-23-new-elf-builder/).

LIEF is pretty light-weight and doesn't require many dependencies.